# using xpath to select an element after another

Tags: xpath, lxml

I've seen similar questions, but the solutions I've seen won't work on the following. I'm far from an XPath expert. I just need to parse some HTML. How can I select the table that follows Header 2. I thought my solution below should work, but apparently not. Can anyone help me out here?

```
content = """<div>
<p><b>Header 1</b></p>
<p><b>Header 2</b><br></p>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Something</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
"""

from lxml import etree
tree = etree.HTML(content)
tree.xpath("//table/following::p/b[text()='Header 2']")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the below **XPATH 1.0** using the Axes [**`preceding`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling).

```
 //table[preceding::p[1]/b[.='Header 2']]
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the code and the docs link. That's helpful.

Answer (score 18):

Some alternatives to @Arup's answer:

```
tree.xpath("//p[b='Header 2']/following-sibling::table[1]")
```

select the first `table` sibling following the `p` containing the `b` header containing "Header 2"

```
tree.xpath("//b[.='Header 2']/following::table[1]")
```

select the first `table` in document order after the `b` containing "Header 2"

See [XPath 1.0 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) for details on the different axes:

- > the ***following*** axis contains all nodes in the same document as the context node that are after the context node in document order, excluding any descendants and excluding attribute nodes and namespace nodes
- > the ***following-sibling*** axis contains all the following siblings of the context node; if the context node is an attribute node or namespace node, the following-sibling axis is empty