# Extracting html tags between header tags using jsoup or regex

Tags: java, regex, string, jsoup

Hi i have a scenario in html file parsing.I am parsing the html file using jsoup, After parsing i want to extract header tags(h1,h3,h4).I used doc.select() but it will return only header tag value but my requirement is i should extract tags between h1 to h3 or h4 and vice-versa.

```
<h4>SECTION 2</h4>
<p>some thing h4.....</p>
<p>some thing h4.....</p>
<p>some thing h4.....</p>
<h3>lawsuit</h3>
<p>some thing h3.....</p>
<p>some thing h3.....</p>
<p>some thing h3.....</p>
<h1>header one </h1>
```

So here first search if the html string contains any H1,H3,H4.
Here we have h4 so including h4 it should search for next h1 or h3,till h3 we extract the string and put it in a separate html file.

First html file contains

```
<h4>SECTION 2</h4>
<p>some thing h4.....</p>
<p>some thing h4.....</p>
<p>some thing h4.....</p>
```

Second html file contains

```
<h3>lawsuit</h3>
<p>some thing h3.....</p>
<p>some thing h3.....</p>
<p>some thing h3.....</p>
```

Third html file contains

```
<h1>header one </h1>
....
....
....
```

Here the html string is dynamic so i want to write a regular expression which should achieve this context as i am new to java i don't know how to achieve this.
Rightnow i used substring,but i need a generic approach either regular expression or jsoup itself.

The code i tried is.

```
try {
    File sourceFile = new File("E://data1.html");
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sourceFile, "UTF-8");
    org.jsoup.nodes.Element elements = doc.body();
    String elementString = StringUtils.substringBetween(elements.toString(),"<h4>", "<h3>");
    System.out.println("elementString::"+elementString);
    File destinationFile = new File("E://sample.html");
    BufferedWriter htmlWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(destinationFile), "UTF-8"));
    htmlWriter.write(elementString);
    htmlWriter.close();
    System.out.println("Completed!!!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: A basic regex which works on your first html is [here](http://regexr.com/3at0q). Can't get it working quite right though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use regex to extract elements from a Xml or HTML document. Regex has limitation on large documents.

Use XPath instead to query a document. For example try to have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19279842/1173755) stackoverflow question. You can use the pipe operator | to have more than one condition in OR.

Something similar to this should work:

```
//h1/following-sibling::p |
//h2/following-sibling::p |
//h3/following-sibling::p |
...
```

Comment: thank you for your response.This will not work for my scenario i want to extract data between two tags.My document is dynamic i cannot decide the preceding tag.It can be either, it faces h1 as first or it might be h2 or h3.So could you please provide me some other alternative or  correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @VelNaga have you resolved your problems using the hints we gave to you?

Comment: i solved the issue using your solution.Sorry for not accepting the answer.Now i accept and upvote it.Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [this](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#html()). You can use this function after you select the desired element(s).

If you are using Jsoup, you don't have to (in fact don't need to) use regex in the case of dom operations.

```
Elements heads = body.select('h1');
// iterate and get inner html of that elements by
String html = head.html();
```

**-- edit --**

Misunderstood the question;

You can determine the h tag's index and use [getElementsByIndexGreaterThan](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByIndexGreaterThan(int)). The rest will be the same.

**-- edit 2 --**

For your particular case; you can iterate after finding first h element:

```
  Elements elements = doc.select("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5");
  for (Element element : elements) {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(element.toString());

     Element next = element.nextElementSibling();
     while (next != null && !next.tagName().startsWith("h")) {
        sb.append(next.toString()).append("\n");
        next = next.nextElementSibling();
     }
     System.out.println(sb);

  }
```

Should work for you.

Comment: The problem is that OP wants to get the text _after_ the headings, so this won't work.

Comment: @px5x2 Thank you for your response.But could you please ellaborate i am not able to get you.